# asp label or <%= embedded code block

Tags: asp.net

I'm recreating an older site and this time looking for inefficiencies. I have previously used a mix of both asp labels being populating server side and leaving embedded code blocks of <%=text here%> to display code retrieved server side.

```
<h4 class="page-title"> Profile Name - <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></h4>
```

and

```
<img class="profile-pic animated" src="<%=ProfilePicURL%>" alt="">
```

Which should I use going forward to ensure the best site performance?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you will find a huge difference in performance there. But if we analyze how each solution works, we could say that `<%= %>` would be faster.

`<%=%>` is a shortcut for `Response.Write`. It's just writing an string into the StreamWriter, whereas a Server Control (an asp:label or an asp:image) has a `Render` process and a reconstruction phase on postback which is relatively more expensive.